# Word/phrase meaning 'calm under pressure'?

Tags: meaning, translation, english-to-german, phrase

I'm looking for a German word/phrase which is roughly equivalent to 'calm under pressure' or 'calm in a storm'.  I read it recently, but cannot remember it!  The sentence went something like 'Bob has shown [phrase]'.  Any ideas?!

Answer (score 2):

*I read it recently, but cannot remember it!*

> Ruhig Blut! Verlier nicht die Nerven!

It's pretty much the same pictures as in English.

> Er bewahrte auch im Sturme Ruhe. (Sturm**e** makes it a bit poetical.)
>
> Auch unter Druck bewahrte sie Ruhe.
>
> Auch unter Druck blieb sie ruhig.
>
> Sie ließ sich nicht aus der Ruhe bringen.
>
> Sie wahrte ihre Contenance.
>
> Sie behielt einen kühlen Kopf.

And, if someone is absolutely unimpressed about what happens or might happen:

> Er hatte die Ruhe weg.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning *»calm under pressure«* or *»calm in a storm«* I would think of:

> - Bob blieb gefasst.
> - Bob blieb gelassen.
> - Bob behielt / bewahrte die Fassung.

Answer (score 0):

Vielleicht war es:

- Bob zeigte Kaltschnäutzigkeit.
- Bob blieb abgeklärt.
- Bob war abgebrüht.